# A Variant of Diagonally Dominant Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that a matrix $\mathbf{A}=[a_{i,j}]$ where $|{a_{i,i}}|\geq\sum_{i\neq{j}}|{a_{i,j}}|, \forall{i}$, is called diagonally dominant.

but what do you call a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ if:
$\sum_{i}|{a_{i,i}}|^2\gg\sum_{i\neq{j}}|{a_{i,j}}|^2, \forall{i}$. In other words most of the matrix power is concentrated in the diagonal.

Cheers

Comment: Some people call them *strongly* diagonally dominant.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel: Sounds reasonable to me. Thanks

Comment: Or *weakly* diagonally dominant for $\geq$ versus *strictly* diagonally dominant for $>$. However, no standard terminology exists for $\gg$.